# Failure to convert DEM into 'boolean' data type

Tags: data-management, pcraster

When I try to convert layer data type (by using PCRaster), I get the following message:

```
QGIS version: 3.36.0-Maidenhead
QGIS code revision: 09951dc0
Qt version: 5.15.3
Python version: 3.9.18
GDAL version: 3.8.4
GEOS version: 3.12.1-CAPI-1.18.1
PROJ version: Rel. 9.3.1, December 1st, 2023
PDAL version: 2.6.0 (git-version: 3fced5)
PCRaster version: QGIS PCRaster Provider version 0.3.0
Algorithm started at: 2024-03-22T16:15:01
Algorithm 'convert layer data type' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'INPUT' : 'D:/PSDP_Geohazards/Debris_Flow/Paper/DEM/Bubur/Strahler_Order_Bubur.sdat', 'INPUT1' : 0, 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\pcraster\operations.py", line 1412, in boolean
_pcraster._rte().checkAndExec(operator, 1)
RuntimeError: arg#1: Number of cells is different than clone or previous argument


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users/User/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\pcraster_tools\processing\algorithms\pcraster_convertdatatype_algorithm.py", line 100, in processAlgorithm
ConversionResult = boolean(InputRaster)
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\pcraster\operations.py", line 1416, in boolean
raise RuntimeError("boolean: %s" % (str(exception)))
RuntimeError: boolean: arg#1: Number of cells is different than clone or previous argument


Execution failed after 0.87 seconds

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'convert layer data type' finished
```

Comment: Whete the question

Comment: Wait, are you really trying to convert floating point elevation data to boolean?

Comment: Yes. Actually I want to calculate the length of the basin, as shown in the following video:

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUPqSKoNGEA

Comment: but stuck somewhere while converting the data to boolean